# scipy.io.mmread cannot read .mtx file

Tags: python, python-2.7, scipy

I have a small .mtx file that I would like to read and later manipulate in Python. 
This is the mtx sample file:

```
Keta := Matrix(4, 4, [[0,1/6,1/2,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]]);
```

In Python I am using this command to read the source file:

```
from scipy.io import mmread, mminfo
Keta1 = mmread('Keta_1.mtx')
```

Then I get this error:

```
ValueError: source is not in Matrix Market format
```

Comment: *"This is the mtx sample file:..."*  If the file contains literally the text `Keta := Matrix(4, 4, [[0,1/6,1/2,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]]);`, then the error message is correct: that is not in the [matrix market format](https://math.nist.gov/MatrixMarket/formats.html).

Comment: hmm but this is saved as .mtx file. Is there a workaround?